# PyInstallerで--noconsoleオプション指定時に作成される.appファイルが起動しない

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, gui, pyinstaller

pyinstallerコマンドでbmi.py(Tkinterを利用してbmiの計算するGUIを表示するファイル)を単一実行ファイル化することはできたのですが、distフォルダ下のbmi.appファイルをダブルクリックしても一瞬Dockにアイコンが表示されて、すぐに消えてしまいます。

### pyinstallerのコマンド

```
pyinstaller bmi.py --onefile --noconsole
```

### bmi.py

```
import tkinter as tk

def calc_bmi():
    h = float(textHeight.get()) / 100
    w = float(textWeight.get())
    bmi = w / h ** 2
    rw = h ** 2 * 22
    per = int(w / rw * 100) - 100
    s = "肥満 {0}% (bmi={1})".format(per, bmi)
    labelResult['text'] = s

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('肥満判定')
win.geometry("500x250")

labelHeight = tk.Label(win, text=u'身長(cm):')
labelHeight.pack()

textHeight = tk.Entry(win)
textHeight.insert(tk.END, '160')
textHeight.pack()

labelWeight = tk.Label(win, text=u'体重(kg):')
labelWeight.pack()

textWeight = tk.Entry(win)
textWeight.insert(tk.END, '70')
textWeight.pack()

labelResult = tk.Label(win, text=u'---')
labelResult.pack()

calcButton = tk.Button(win, text=u'計算')
calcButton["command"] = calc_bmi
calcButton.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

#### 環境

macOS Catalina
バージョン10.15.7

Python 3.6.12
PyInstaller 4.0
Tkinter 8.6

#### 調べたこと

pyinstallerのドキュメントをみると--noconsoleオプションに関して、以下のように記述されていました。

> WindowsおよびMacOS X：標準I / O用のコンソールウィンドウを提供しません。**Mac OS Xでは、これによりOS X.appバンドルの構築もトリガーされます。**

確かにdistフォルダ下にはbmi(Unix実行ファイル)とbmi.app(アプリケーションファイル)が生成されています。

dist
├── bmi
└── bmi.app

bmi(Unix実行ファイル)をダブルクリックすると、コンソールが表示されてからGUIが表示されるのですが、--noconsoleオプションが機能していません。
おそらく、bmi(Unix実行ファイル)は--nosonsoleを指定しなくても同じように作成され同じ挙動なので、bmi.app(アプリケーションファイル)のほうがコンソールなしで起動できるのが正解だと思われます。

初めてpyinstallerを触ってみて調べても解決策がなかなか見つからなかったため、質問を投稿させて頂きました。
どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 古い記事ですが、何か出来ていそうなもの。[pyinstallerの*.specファイル作成法。](https://qiita.com/cheuora/items/39b3203400e1e15248ed) 少し新しいが未解決なもの。[Hide console window while making Tkinter executable for mac os usind pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57906435/9014308) とても古い記事でpyinstallerでは無いがconsoleは2種類あるというものらしい。[Hide console for Tkinter app on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1810497/9014308) MacOSは古いですがクロスプラットフォームな例。[PyInstaller - Standalone Python Applications for MacOS, Windows, and Linux](https://jacob-brown.github.io/2019-09-10-pyinstaller/) あたりが参考になるかも。

Comment: kunifさん、コメントして頂きありがとうございます。https://jacob-brown.github.io/2019-09-10-pyinstaller/
←こちらのサイトの方がgitにこのエラーを解決するpythonのスクリプトを公開してくださっていて、それを実行することで解決できました。回答にまとめておきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄で紹介して頂いた以下のサイトが参考になりました。

[PyInstaller - Standalone Python Applications for MacOS, Windows, and Linux](https://jacob-brown.github.io/2019-09-10-pyinstaller/)

こちらのサイトによると以下のように書かれていました。

> -F, –onefile - App is bundled into a single file.Create a one-file bundled executable.If you are a MacOS user don’t use –onefile, I’ll elaborate below.

簡単な和訳
*-F, -onefile オプションで一つのファイルにバンドルできます。単一実行ファイルが作れます。もしあなたがMacOSユーザーなら、-onefileオプションは使わないでください。下に詳しく述べます。*

そしてその理由が以下のように記述されていました。

> Currently the pyinstaller build on MacOS uses an incompatible version of tcl, resulting in the app immediately crashing when it opens (i.e. if you follow the above). Below is a method which allows the application to be opened by editing the init.tcl file. I have written a python script which makes these changes.

簡単な和訳
*現在のMacOSで動くpyinstallerはtclの互換性がないバージョンです。その結果、アプリ起動時にすぐにクラッシュしてしまいます。以下の方法によりinit.tclファイルを作ることでアプリケーションを開くことを可能にします。私はその変更を行うためのpythonのスクリプトを記述しました。*

このサイトを作成された方が [GitHub にそのスクリプトを公開されている](https://github.com/jacob-brown/TCLChanger) ので、単一実行ファイル化したいファイル (私の場合bmi.py) のあるディレクトリで、その GitHub のフォルダをクローンし実行することで解決できました。

以下が解決のためのコマンドです。(MacOSの場合)

- 手順1 pyinstallerコマンド

  ```
  pyinstaller --noconsole bmi.py
  ```
- 手順2 GitHub からクローンするコマンド

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/jacob-brown/TCLChanger.git
  ```
- 手順3 クローンしたスクリプトを実行

  ```
  python TCLChanger/TCLChanger.py
  ```

同じように困っている方の参考になれば幸いです。